# Users can publish even when item has blank fields marked with required validation rule

Tags: content-editor, workflow, validation

I have Sitecore 8.2, have the template for my item assigned to our custom workflow, I have all `validation rules` set to Required for the fields in question.

Yet I can move the item through the workflow without saving it (the validation rules prevent me from saving without filling these fields in), and finally can actually publish the item.

What am I missing?  Shouldn't I be prevented from doing this if Required is added as a Workflow validation rule for a field that is never filled in?

Comment: You logged in as an admin users?  admin users can do whatever they want.

Comment: Nope, logged in as non-admin users.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your workflow details (all states, commands, and actions)? Do you have a validation action somewhere in your workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have a **Validation Action** item somewhere in your workflow. Take a look at the **Sample Workflow** for an example:

[image: Validation action selected in Sitecore content tree]

The placement of this action means that when a user executes the **Approve** command, Sitecore will try to validate the item.

To add it, add an item of template **Validation Action** (`/sitecore/templates/System/Workflow/Validation Action`):

[image: Validation action fields]